# How do I "Rebuild and Run" using CodeBlocks in one single action?

Tags: codeblocks, fortran90

Is there a way to have a button or shortcut to "Rebuild and run"? Because I have to click "Rebuild" and then click "Run" every time. This is very annoying...

PS.: For the project I'm working on, "Build and Run" button is not enough because I need to REbuild the entire project every time I change something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature currently.
You can bind "Clean" to a shortcut, for example Shift-F9, and then run "Build and Run" using F9.

But CodeBlocks is open source, so if this isn't good enough for you either implement this yourself or suggest it on http://forums.codeblocks.org/

For binding the "Clean" to a shortcut, you go into Settings -> Editor -> Keyboard shortcuts.